# How to communicate with a Unity application via WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-game-engine

I am completely new to [Unity](https://unity3d.com), and I am about to build a small project which requires the following:

> An external application must be able to send messages to a Unity application to request the rendering of specific objects.

#### Implementation strategy

Basically my idea, to build this, is to have my Unity application expose a service endpoint (using [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf)) which can be pointed by whatever other application that can send it HTTP requests specifying the objects to render.

#### WCF + Unity

I know that Unity basically runs on [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/), however I am not sure whether it supports WCF. So please consider the following questions:

- Is it possible to use `System.ServiceModel` in a Unity application?
- Is it possible to have a Unity application create a WCF web service and expose an endpoint to listen to external requests?
- I think this scenario is kinda basic from the point of view of multiplayer gaming, so if this exact scenario is not the best practice, which one is?

Comment: 5 seconds perusing the Mono docs yields a possible answer to your first question - https://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/wcf/

Comment: Thanks, I did not consider the possibility to use the Mono doc actually... Feel a bit stupid :P You can post an answer on this 'cause it basically answers my question